# Backbone event attachment:compat:ready can't hook

Tags: plugin-development, backbone

I want to ask question about events in backbone. I have problem to run some function when hook is triggerd.

I want to

```
      wp.media.view.AttachmentCompat.prototype .on("attachment:compat:ready", function (e) {
            console.log("READYY");
        });
```

But this isn't working. What object handle the events of AttachmentCompat ?
Maybe i do it to early ?

I was able to run my function by extending , but for me isn't best way.

```
           var AttachmentCompatNew = wp.media.view.AttachmentCompat.extend({
            postSave: function () {
                this.controller.trigger('attachment:compat:ready', ['ready']);



            }
        });

        wp.media.view.AttachmentCompat.prototype = AttachmentCompatNew.prototype;
```

Can some one help me to understand how i can trigger my functions on diffrent events ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     if (wp.media) {
            wp.media.view.AttachmentCompat.prototype.on("ready", function (e) {
                console.log("Kompat Ready mokor 12");
            });
}
```

This event name is "ready" :) works now fine . Maybe this will help someone.